# Multi-Line EditText with character wrap but not word wrap

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

I use EditText control with a **multi-lines** mode in my Android Studio app. 
Is there a way that EditText will perform **character-wrap** (line breaks) instead of word-wrap?